Shift object to last index of an array
Let's say I have this array of objects:
var array = [
    {
        "identifier": "A",
    },
    {
        "identifier": "B",
    },
    {
        "identifier": "C",
    },
    {
        "identifier": "D",
    },
]

How can I map/reduce this array to get this result:
var array = [
    {
        "identifier": "A",
    },
    {
        "identifier": "C",
    },
    {
        "identifier": "D",
    },
    {
        "identifier": "B",
    },
]

In other words, how can I put "B" at the end of array no matter how large the array is?
array.map((o) => {
  if (o.identifier === 'B') {
     // do what here?
  }
 return o;
})


Find the index where identifier == "B", then splice the array at that index (this returns an array of the deleted item(s), then push the item(s) to the end.

Mapping gives you an array of the same length in the same order, for a start. What you're doing is sorting.

As @jonrsharpe pointed out, you can apply sort():


const array = [
  {
    identifier: 'A',
  },
  {
    identifier: 'B',
  },
  {
    identifier: 'C',
  },
  {
    identifier: 'D',
  },
];
array.sort((a, b) => (b.identifier === 'B' ? -1 : 0));
console.log(array);




You could take a generator and delay the wanted item.


function* moveToEnd(array, identifier) {
    let last = [];
    
    for (const element of array)
        if (element.identifier === identifier) last.push(element);
        else yield element;
        
    yield* last;
}

const
    array = [{ identifier: "A" }, { identifier: "B" }, { identifier: "C" }, { identifier: "D" }],
    result = [...moveToEnd(array, 'B')];

console.log(result);




Start by finding the index where identifier == "B", then splice the array at that index (this returns an array of the deleted item(s), then push the removed item(s) to the end of the original array.


var array = [{
    "identifier": "A",
  },
  {
    "identifier": "B",
  },
  {
    "identifier": "C",
  },
  {
    "identifier": "D",
  },
]
const bIndex = array.findIndex(arr => (arr.identifier == "B"));
const removed = array.splice(bIndex,1);
array.push(...removed);
console.log("resorted array",array)




For mapping (i.e. creating a new array), you can concatenate the slices (before, after, itself):


const array = [{identifier:"A"},{identifier:"C"},{identifier:"D"},{identifier:"B"}];

const i = array.findIndex(o => o.identifier === 'X');
const result = i < 0 ? [...array]
                     : [...array.slice(0, i), ...array.slice(i+1), array[i]];
console.log(result);



If you are really looking for a solution that uses the map method, then use the index parameter that the map-callback gets:


const array = [{identifier:"A"},{identifier:"C"},{identifier:"D"},{identifier:"B"}];

let move = null;
const result = array.map((o, i, array) => {
    if (o.identifier === 'B') move = o;
    return array[i + !!move] ?? move;
});
console.log(result);




var given_array = [ { "identifier": "A" }, { "identifier": "B" }, { "identifier": "C" }, { "identifier": "D" } ]; const index = array.findIndex(o => o.identifier === 'B'); if(!index ==-1){ const item.splice(index, 1); given_array.push(item); console.log(given_array)

Looks like there are some issues with the code. const item.splice(index, 1) isn't valid syntax

You can achieve the desired result in one simple Array.prototype.sort() call, with a very simple sort predicate.
In the example I've shortened identifier to id to make the code more readable.


const arr = [{"id": "A"},{"id": "B"},{"id": "C"},{"id": "D"}];

const sortedArr = arr.sort(
  (a, b) => a.id === 'B' 
              ? 1 
              : b.id === 'B' 
                ? -1 
                : 0
);

console.log(sortedArr);



